# Ruby Socket Programming Waiting for Client Input

Tags: ruby

I am trying to implement a small script that will create a server, wait for a client to connect, create a new thread for the client and then process client requests. The first request from the client will be a HELO text and the server must respond with the HELO text followed by IP Address, Port Number and a Student Number. I have got this bit working.

The next request will be any random string and this must not return anything. I have got this bit working.

The last request will be a KILL_SERVICE request which must close the server. I am not sure how to do this. The other issue is that my program will only work with one command at a time. I do not know how to deal with one command and then wait for the next command from the client. My server code is below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
require 'socket'         
port = 8888     
puts "Starting Up Server"
server = TCPServer.open(port)  

while (client = server.accept) 
  Thread.start do
    input = client.gets

    if input.start_with?("HELO")
      client.puts "#{input}IP:#{client.peeraddr[2]}\nPort:#{port}\nStudentID:[2]\n"
    elsif input == "KILL_SERVICE\n"
      client.puts "KILL"
    else
      puts input        
    end
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as your code leaves the `Thread.start` block that thread is considered finished. If you want it to stick around you need to wrap it in a loop:

```
while (client = server.accept)
  Thread.start do
    client_running = true

    while (client_running)
      # ... Your code
    end
  end
end
```

Then, if any of those commands should stop the thread, set `client_running = false` and the loop will exit. To force shut-down the whole thing, `exit(0)` will end the process.

**Update:** Added block on how to handle shutting down the server itself, not just the connection.

Comment: Thank you very much for that. The last issue I have is to kill the server. Would you be able to help with that?

Comment: I've updated this with notes on how to handle the main process not just a single thread.

Answer (score 0):

You need to continue waiting for input from the client after accepting the connection.

```
while (client = server.accept) 
  Thread.start do
    while input = client.gets
      # process input
    end
  end 
end
```

When you receive `KILL_SERVICE` you need to close the client using `client.close` and break out of the `while` loop using `break`. Once you've broken out of the `while` loop, the thread handling that client will exit.